# Django get old url

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In django views,From the request how would we know from which page this view was called

```
 def password_change(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      u=request.user
      u.set_password(request.POST.get('new_password'))
      u.save()
      post_change_redirect= //Need old link here 
      return HttpResponseRedirect(post_change_redirect)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `request.path`

Comment: Lets say the users access links /home from which change password, is called and on change of password this view is called ,so basically i want to be redirected to /home

Comment: then additional parameter is needed. add something like callback=/home

Answer (score 1):

Normally a variable in the query string (accessible via `request.GET`) is used to instruct the view where to redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.path
```

will return the full path (not including the domain).

e.g. `/music/bands/the_beatles/`